# how to get destination info(bank and card details) on stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

Let's say I'm getting payouts information https://stripe.com/docs/api/payouts/list
I want to get the destination info, so if we take the example from the docs:
[image]
I want the details from that destination, I don't mean the specific details like the exact credit card number, but the info when going on the page itself, this one:

[image]

It's not working listing the banks accounts https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_bank_accounts/list , I'm getting zero results when list them all

I'm using Golang library but I think this solution can be solved by others programming languages

I'm also using expandable fields but I get blank results on bank_account and card details

[image]

[image]

what is interesting however, is when debugging the page, they make request to `v1/payouts/{id}` with `expand[]: balance_transaction` and the returned data contains the bank information, but when I do it with their API, that info is not returned back
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Payout [`destination`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payouts/object#payout_object-destination) is [expandable](https://stripe.com/docs/expand), meaning you can have it replaced with the full object by sending you request with `expand[]=destination` or for a list command `data.destination`.

Comment: thanks for the anwer but I already tried that; please check the update question

Comment: Hhmm have you tried retrieving the External Account with that Id? https://stripe.com/docs/api/external_account_bank_accounts/retrieve

Comment: I'm getting permissions error "This application does not have the required permissions for this endpoint on account" which permission should I have to view that info? I don't want specific details, just the bank name at least

Comment: As documented, you can only see the details here for custom accounts. Sounds like you're talking about a Standard connected account and you don't have access to this.